# Computing the bases of $\mathbb Z _2 ^n$ over $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, computer-science, computational-mathematics

I have to compute the number of bases of the vector space $\mathbb Z _2 ^n$
over $\mathbb Z_2$ and the vectors of each such basis.

For example for $n=2$, the number of bases is $6$  the vectors of each such basis are:
$((0,1),(1,0)) \ ;((0,1),(1,1));\ ((1,0),(0,1));\ ((1,0),(1,1));\ ((1,1),(0,1));\ ((1,1),(1,0))$ 
In my algorithm I managed to make a list that consists of all the vectors(I managed to compute the number of bases too). And to get the bases I was thinking to get all combinations of $p = dim \ V$  ($2$ for $n=2$,$3$ for $n=3$,...) and to check if they are linearly independent. And because the number of vector choosen is equal to the dimension, it will be a system of generators too, so a basis. But I don't know to make an algorithm if the vectors are linearly independent. Can somebody help me,please? (I am coding in Python)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the first vector can be any nonzero vector $u_1$.  The second is any vector $u_2$ other than $0$ or $u_1$.  The third is any vector other than the linear combinations of $u_1$ and $u_2$ (of which there are $4$)...

Comment: And the fourth one will be different than the linear combinations of $u_1,u_2,u_3$?

Comment: Yes, that's right.